# Variables comparison php (strcmp), equality fails

Tags: php

I have function

```
if ((isset($_REQUEST['onlinca']) && $_REQUEST['onlinca'] == true)) {
    $resultintca = mysqli_query($maincon, "SELECT * FROM Exten");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultintca)) {
        $indexintca = $row['Index'];
        if (($indexintca !== $v[6])) {
            echo "notEqual";
            print_r ($indexintca);
            print_r ($v[6]);
            echo "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

It outputs that

```
notEqual301304
notEqual302304
notEqual303304
notEqual304304
notEqual305304
notEqual306304
notEqual307304
```

And so on,but Equal304304 does not have to be printed as the variables are identical.
I also tried to do that using **strcmp** but the output is the same.

Comment: You should really add the code where you are using `strcmp` to your question, since the question title mentions it.

Comment: Do you know that `strcmp` returns `0` when strings are equal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!==` is a [strict comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) that compares both value *and* type. So the odds are `$indexintca` and `$v[6]` are not the same data type. (`$indexintca` is probably a string and `$v[6]` an integer). So change `!==` to `!=` so you only compare values:

```
if (($indexintca != $v[6])) {
```

Comment: Changed but the output is the same

Comment: Try to var_dump($indexintca) and var_dump($v[6]) and make sure there isn't anything funky going on

Comment: Notced a space in second string string(3) "304" string(24) "304 "

Comment: Ahh, that errant space. Gets us every time ;)

Comment: Solved using     $v[6] = str_replace(' ', '', $v[6]);

Comment: You could also have used `trim()`.